# Not being able to delete file from local storage using PHP

Tags: php, file, xampp, local-storage

I am using PHP. I have a file in local storage of Xampp. I have been trying to delete that using `unlink`. I tried copying the relative path and pasted in `unlink`, but it does not delete the file from local storage. I even tried pasting the `path`, so not the relative one, but it still does not delete the files. Can someone reckon what I might be doing wrong?

My code:

```
unlink("userdir/username/181");
```

As someone mention in comments I try changing the permission. I tried  `sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/hemlatamahaur/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs`

but it still says Operation not permitted. What shall I do?

Comment: Maybe the user running the script doesn't have permission to remove it.

Comment: @Barmar I do have permission for userdir, but inside that it has `username` and when I try to change the permission for it, it says `The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission` how can I fix that assuming it has to do with the permission?

Comment: The system administrator needs to change the permissions so the webserver username has write permission to the `username` directory.

Answer (score 0):

this code working for me!

```
// first check location exist or not
if (file_exists(#locationfile)) {
    unlink(#locationfile);
}
```